# Is a commit between DELETE/INSERT queries relevant in SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, commit

I am writing a code in Python by using the `sqlite3` module. Do I need to perform a commit between the two following queries:

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE user="foobar";
INSERT INTO XXX ... ; -- new stuff about user "foobar"
```

What I want is deleting anything related to "foobar" before adding some (new) stuff, but I would like to be sure that order of both queries will be kept during the commit.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Oh, my question is only related to the commit (as stated in my message); I am perfectly aware that order is important in your question (1)!

Comment: The two operations should be a single unit of work.  You'll need to turn auto commit off for the duration of the transaction and commit at the end.